# Python Error handling for an input requiring a integer

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

I would like to implement error handling so that if the user puts in anything besides an integer they get asked for the correct input. I believe try/except would work but I am wondering how I can get it to check for both a correct number within a range and ensuring there are no other characters. I have pasted my code below for review.

Thanks!

```
# Rock Paper Scissors

import random as rdm
print("Welcome to Rock/Paper/Scissors, you will be up against the computer in a best of 3")

# game_counter = 0

human_1 = input("Please enter your name: ")

GameOptions = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

hmn_score = 0
cpt_score = 0

rps_running = True


def rps():
    global cpt_score, hmn_score
    while rps_running:

        hmn = int(input("""Please select from the following:
                                1 - Rock
                                2 - Paper
                                3 - Scissors
            \n""")) - 1

        while not int(hmn) in range(0, 3):
            hmn = int(input("""Please select from the following:
                                            1 - Rock
                                            2 - Paper
                                            3 - Scissors
                        \n""")) - 1

        print('You Chose: ' + GameOptions[hmn])

        cpt = rdm.randint(0, 2)

        print('Computer Chose: ' + GameOptions[cpt] + '\n')

        if hmn == cpt:
            print('Tie Game!')

        elif hmn == 0 and cpt == 3:
            print('You Win')
            hmn_score += 1
        elif hmn == 1 and cpt == 0:
            print('You Win')
            hmn_score += 1
        elif hmn == 2 and cpt == 1:
            print('You Win')
            hmn_score += 1
        else:
            print('You Lose')
            cpt_score += 1

        game_score()
        game_running()


def game_score():
    global cpt_score, hmn_score
    print(f'\n The current score is {hmn_score} for you and {cpt_score} for the computer \n')


def game_running():
    global rps_running
    if hmn_score == 2:
        rps_running = False
        print(f"{human_1} Wins!")
    elif cpt_score == 2:
        rps_running = False
        print(f"Computer Wins!")
    else:
        rps_running = True


rps()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you can do something like the following

```py
options = range(1, 4)
while True:
    try:
        choice = int(input("Please select ...etc..."))
        if(choice in options):
            break
        raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Please enter a number {list(options)}")
print(f"You chose {choice}")
```

As for the a code review, there's a specific stack exchange for that, see [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will move this to the appropriate forum section.

Comment: No problem, you can mark this as the answer if you believe it is :)